# Codeigniter Pagination 3rd page link becoming disabled

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

Here is my controller :

```
class Comment extends CI_Controller {

function article() {
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->model('comment_m');
            $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/comment/article/'.$id;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('comment_article')->num_rows();
            $config['per_page'] = 5;
    $config['num_links'] = 5;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            echo $this->uri->segment(4);
            $data['c_review'] = $this->comment_m->getarticle($id, $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));

            $this->load->view('comment_v', $data);
}
}
```

Here is my model:

```
class Comment_m extends CI_Model{

function getarticle($id,$limit,$start) {
    $this->db->select('name, content');
    $this->db->from('comment_article');
            $this->db->where('article_id', $id); 
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $q = $this->db->get();

    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($q->result() as $c_review) {
            $data[] = $c_review;
        }
        return $data;
    }       

}
}
```

The pagination is working fine if I have less than or equal to 10 articles (2 pages only), but if I have a third pagination link then the 3rd link becomes unclicable and is not an anchor tag.
I have used an identical pagination in my other page which is working fine but this one is causing this problem.

Here is the link to the picture of the paginated page. Here the highlighted page is 3 while the active page is still 1 so 3rd page is uncliable.

[This is the link to the image](http://s20.postimage.org/v4pdir8n1/paginate.png)

And this is my other implementation which I am not able to achieve with this pagination but this is what I want : Here the current page is 1st and total of 13 items are there with 5 items per page.

[This is link to the desired implementation](http://s20.postimage.org/z3r6fbmnx/paginate.png)

Comment: try **$config['first_url'] = "localhost/ci/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/comment/article/".$id;**

Comment: also try enabling the output profiler and/or ci logs to check what happening

Comment: @Badaboooooom from where can we enable the output profiler and ci logs?

Comment: $this->output->enable_profiler(true); //put this wherever you want (views/model/controller .. it's the same)

Comment: logs can be enabled from config/config.php search for log_treshold

Comment: okay I am testing this now

Comment: let me know or we can init a chat, why not

Comment: @Badaboooooom I set the log_threshold to 1 then no errors are there...and I set it to 4 then I did not see any unwanted things.And profiler also is showing desired results only.

Comment: ok can't help actually without the pagination live preview

Comment: the pagination is working fine and the info is shown if we manually type the url of 3rd page but the page is itself not accessible from pagination link.

Comment: so try replacing the core Pagination class, downloading new one, is the only thing i can image without live code sorry, do you use some sort of js pagination or do you modify any CI pagination code? If not this should work

Comment: No I have not modified the core pagination class. And with similar model and controller it is working also but it is not working in this case. I will try to debug it myself and post the solution.

Comment: ok it seems somenthing out coming from the html/js not from the php anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well as point of view you have problem with total_rows it gives you number of selected rows from db not total count better to use count_all or count_all_result if you are using any where clause just change it

```
from
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('comment_article')->num_rows();

to 
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('comment_article')->count_all();
```

one more change this will  help you while your deploying project on other server

```
from
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/comment/article/'.$id;

to
$config['base_url'] = base_url('comment/article/'.$id); // it will automatically add default base_url
```

most importand you have to add $config['uri_segment'] you have to tell which segment is page number by default is 3

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
```

have look on Pagination doc on CI site

Comment: I think that was the case. It waas taking the 3rd url segment but I wanted the 4th one. It is working now.